# External libraries within a shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, osl

Can I call functions from external libraries (.dll or .a) within a shader script? 
I want to be able to communicate to an external process and/or write a "log" for each point in the surface of an object.
I know that will slow a lot the rendering but the main point is to "log" the render.
I need simulate a detector (like a CCD) within blender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can call external libraries but you can certainly log messages to the console using 'printf(...)', 'warning(...)' or 'error(...)' function calls. For example :

```
printf("Point %f,%f,%f\n", P[0], P[1], P[2]);
```

This can produce the following output :

```
Point 0.352600 -0.724535 0.683879
Point 0.377360 -0.151356 0.841542
Point -0.081450 -0.115284 0.909532
Point -0.075156 -0.181691 0.885011
Point -0.018898 -0.221594 0.864882
....
```

The 'warning(...)' and 'error(...)' calls work a similar way but include additional formatting around the output string :

```
WARNING: Shader warning [my_shader]: Point -0.320504 -0.812141 0.157532
WARNING: Shader warning [my_shader]: Point 0.304608 -0.822310 0.270545
WARNING: Shader warning [my_shader]: Point 0.626177 0.138751 -0.099909
```

Looking at the OSL spec, there is also an 'fprintf(...)' function that accepts an additional argument for the output filename and will append the output to that file (rather than having to capture the console output and extract the details from there). However, my particular version of Blender (2.76b) does not seem to support that - it's presumably implemented at a later version.

Comment: Thank you very much!! The fprintf is good for me! I didn't see it in the specification. Do I need to include the stdio.h (like in C language)? If there was some kind of socket communication it would be absolutely perfect!

Comment: You don't need to include stdio.h or anything - it's included automatically as part of OSL.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about the fprintf but since the shader ia local function, opening a file every time would make the slowdown inviable (I can handle slow, but open a file for each ray seems dangerous). Is there a way to make a global variable?

Thanks again!

Comment: @ninguem Yeah - you're probably right - that wouldn't be the most efficient way of doing things. Personally (and running on Linux) I would start blender with a command such as "blender | grep '^MYSTUFF' |tee somelogfile" which would filter off anything starting with MYSTUFF into somelogfile. You could then just use "printf('MYSTUFF .... rest of message', ...)" to output to the log. However, I don't know how you'd do the equivalent on Windows (assuming that's what you're using) - maybe just "blender > somelogfile" and extract the details later. I presume Mac would be similar to Linux...?

Comment: I'm using MacOs. Wonderful tip the one you just gave with grep... Thank you very very much!!!
Now I just need to figure out how to implement some kind of "global" (my own, not the P, N, etc...).

Comment: In short what I need is a way to save the luminosity of each point in a plane (for instance). I'm simulating the detector of an instrument for a wavefront sensor. I implemented my own retrace in python so I have a panel that I can control everything. But that is limited... I can benefit for the functions already implemented in the shader (like normals, transformations, etc.)
Hence, what I need is to divide the surface of a plane in (say) 16x16 regions and "count" the number of hits in each region...

Answer (score 0):

Figure out a workaround.

Implemented a python script that processes the output form the console and piped that with blender

$ blender | grep --line-buffered "MARK" | ./pipeServerPython.py

the script pipeServerPython.py interprets each line that is produced by a print in the shader.

For that to work we need to unbuffer everyone (notice --line-biffered in grep). Also we need to nonOptimize the shader compilation.

To unbuffer blender, just create the PYTHONUNBUFFERED environment variable (export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=on). To nonOptimize the shader, set OSL_OPTIONS="optimize=0" also as an environment variable.

Thats it. Now we have a "listener" in python for every hit in the shader.