# OSL string functions

Tags: cycles-render-engine, osl

I've read about string functions in OSL lang. specification but it didn't give a clear explanation how to use them correctly.

I'm interested in *void* **warning**() and *void* **error**() functions.
Are there any examples how to use them during the working process?

Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

The 'warning(...)' and 'error(...)' functions behave very similarly to the 'printf' function in that they output strings to the console output.

For example, in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/98833/29586) the printf function is used to format output to the console using a command as follows :

```
printf("Point %f,%f,%f\n", P[0], P[1], P[2]);
```

This outputs the formatted string (with each %f replaced by one of the following arguments) to the console.

The warning(...) and error(...) functions work similarly except each call outputs a line formatted with the work 'WARNING' or 'ERROR' and details of where the function was called from (the shader function) similar to the following :

```
WARNING: Shader warning [my_shader]: Point -0.320504 -0.812141 0.157532
```

With the syntax being identical to 'printf' :

```
warning("Point %f,%f,%f\n", P[0], P[1], P[2]);
```